# Pushwoosh Remote API DOT NET Example

Tags: push-notification, push, pushwoosh

My Phonegap application can receive notifications from pushwoosh panel. I want to integrate it in my DOT NET Application with help of remote api.

Answer (score 1):

You can find example at http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/createmessage

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace WebApplication1
{
   public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           string pwAuth = "YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN";
           string pwApplication = "PW_APPLICATION_CODE";
           JObject json = new JObject(
               new JProperty("application", pwApplication),
               new JProperty("auth", pwAuth),
               new JProperty("notifications",
                   new JArray(
                       new JObject(
                           new JProperty("send_date", "now"),
                           new JProperty("content", "test"),
                           new JProperty("wp_type", "Toast"),
                           new JProperty("wp_count", 3),
                           new JProperty("data",
                               new JObject(
                                   new JProperty("custom", "json data"))),
                           new JProperty("link", "http://pushwoosh.com/"),
                           new JProperty("conditions",
                               new JArray(
                                   (object)new JArray("Color", "EQ", "black")))))));
           PWCall("createMessage", json);
       }
       private void PWCall(string action, JObject data)
       {
           Uri url = new Uri("https://cp.pushwoosh.com/json/1.3/" + action);
           JObject json = new JObject(new JProperty("request", data));
           DoPostRequest(url, json);
       }
       private void DoPostRequest(Uri url, JObject data)
       {
           HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
           req.ContentType = "text/json";
           req.Method = "POST";
           using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream()))
           {
               streamWriter.Write(data.ToString());
           }
           HttpWebResponse httpResponse;
           try
           {
               httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
           }
           catch (Exception exc)
           {
               throw new Exception(string.Format("Problem with {0}, {1}", url, exc.Message));
           }
           using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
           {
               var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
               Page.Response.Write(responseText);
           }
       }
   }
}
```